# Set Windows to use system clock as UTC

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, time-zone, utc

While dual-booting Windows and Linux, Linux sets the system time to UTC, so Windows thinks it's midnight near mid-morning. Is there any other way to tell Windows to use UTC? I've seen the registry tweak proposed [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2006/06/20/Set-hardware-clock-to-UTC-on-Windows-_2800_or-how-to-make-the-clock-work-on-a-Mac-Book-Pro_2900_.aspx) and other places. This does not work on my computer (Windows 7 32-bit).

For reference, the registry entry is this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux usually uses a tool called `hwclock` to interface with the hardware clock. Depending on your distribution, you should be able to modify the system startup scripts to make `hwclock` reread and store the time using current system timezone.

In Ubuntu, you can enable local time mode [by editing `/etc/default/rcS`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple%20Boot%20Systems%20Time%20Conflicts) to:

```
UTC=no
```

I know, not exactly what you asked for, but it does make both OSes use the same clock offset.

Comment: Getting Linux to use local time will have to be good enough. Thanks!